# How to remove repetition when there is a common condition

Tags: python, if-statement

How do i remove the repetitions

```
 if a < 2 or b < 2 or c < 2 or d < 2: 
       pass #logic
```

I want to remove the repetitions. Something like this:

```
if (a,b,c,d) < 2:
   pass #logic
```

Comment: You might want to use a list or dictionary instead of a sequence of variables. This will allow you to use loop and comprehensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another slightly different way is to check if the smallest variable is less than the target value. In other words, if the smallest variable ***is not*** less than the target - then surely none of them is:

```py
if min(a, b, c, d) < 2:
    # do something
```

This however needs to actually find the minimal value behind the scenes and loses the short-circuiting advantage of using `any` with a generator expression.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't import `numpy` just for this as other answers suggest. It's probably overkill.

I would do something like:

```
condition = lambda x: x < 2
if any(condition(x) for x in (a, b, c, d)):
    # whatever you want
```

Or more compact (but less reusable):

```
if any(x < 2 for x in (a, b, c, d)):
    # whatever you want
```

Answer (score 1):

When using numpy this can be done with .all() and .any():

```
import numpy as np

array = np.asarray([1,2,3])

if (array < 2).any():
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')

#output: True

if (array < 2).all():
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')

#output: False
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, use `generator expression` to reduce computing time

```
if True in (i < 2 for i in [a,b,c,d]):
   pass #logic
```

Comment: This works, but `any(...)` is more idiomatic than `True in (...)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would have used combination of Numpy and [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) here.

For example:

```
a, b, c, d = 10, 10, 10, 10
```

Convert it into a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([a, b, c, d])
```

And now you can do this:

```
if any(arr < 2):
    pass #logic
```

Answer (score -1):

Use built-in `any` function:

```py
if any(map(lambda x: x < 2, (a, b, c, d))):
    pass  # whatever here
```

Comment: you can also use `filter`. `len(filter(lambda x: x>=2, (a, b, c, d))) == 0`

Comment: @cup11 This way checks that ***all*** numbers are less 2. The question asks for ***any***. Maybe `len(filter(lambda x: x<2, (a, b, c, d))) != 0` would work but seems like an unnecessary complication

Comment: @Tomerikoo You're right. I didn't notice that.